# Removing same audio sections from audio files

Tags: audio, audio-processing, audacity

As a collecter I've thousands of audio files which downloaded from podcasting services. All feeds start with a 15 seconds same introduction. That's very annoying for me so I tried crop all of them.

But all of them are not regular. The voiced presentations are the exactly same but some of them...

- ... are starting at 00:00 or at 00:05 or at any seconds which we don't know
- ... have not the introduction on startup

I couldn't determine which seconds should crop.

The question: How can we crop the all audio files according to specific audio clip?

In other sayings "detect same part and remove it" ?

Comment: Have you tried comparing two of the intro clips visually? Do they look exactly the same or close to it? If so, then you could perform a simple search. Otherwise, it could be pretty difficult.

Comment: It might be helpful to let us know what software platform(s) you'd be comfortable using for the solution.

Comment: Hi @jacket. Two intro clips look exactly the same or close. Dear Ross Bencina You're right. I don't know also which software platform(s) I need. Maybe Audacity.

Comment: @RarLines Stackoverflow is a programming community, I assume that you know how to program a computer to process audio?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you already have a way to crop the files at a specific point. So the problem boils down to working out where the intro ends in each clip. Here's how I would do it:

- First, manually isolate the intro audio in a separate file/buffer.
- For each clip, you need to work out where in the clip the intro audio occurs. Do this by computing a [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) between the intro audio and the main clip. The correct offset will be the one with the highest correlation coefficient. (You could also look for the  minimum in a mean-difference, which is equivalent.)
- Once you know where the intro audio is, you can calculate your crop position.

There are a few obvious optimisations:

- Only search for the intro audio in the first (say) 30 seconds of each clip.
- Don't search for the whole intro audio, just the last 1/2 second.
- If you're not 100% sure that the audio is there, you might want to set a threshold for acceptance.

Comment: Thanks for reply but stackoverflow blows me up! How can I do "search" and "set a threshold" I couldn't find the required software platforms